# Bi-directional udp communication does not work in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, udp

I could like to do a bi-directional communication between server and client. I end up with a problem.

1. I am getting the host ip from server and then connecting to it. but i am not sure how to get it from one def to another.
2. If i specify host ip directly it works. But i dont want it like that. 
   Please post your idea.

client program:

```
import socket
import os
import re
class cont():
    def get_bd(self):
        def receive_bd(self):
            # receive broadcast
            def get_ip_data(ether_adapter):

                ip_data = os.popen("ifconfig " + ether_adapter)
                for line in ip_data:
                    match2 = re.search(r'broadcast\s+(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)', line)
                    if match2:
                        bd = match2.group(1)
                        return bd

            if __name__ == "__main__":
                ethernet_card = "wlp1s0"
                inet_list = get_ip_data(ethernet_card)
                # print(inet_list)
            self.sock.bind((inet_list, 12345))
            msg, client = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
            a = (msg.decode())
            #here i receive the ip of my server to the client
            host = a

    def send_ls(self):
        #i want the host i received in that receive_bd as a host here
        host= "here?if i give direct ip of server it works which i dont want to do but directly get it from receive_bd "
        port=4343
        address=host,port
        client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        while (True):
            msg=input("Controller 1 :")
            client.sendto(bytearray(msg,"utf-8"),address)
            reply=client.recvfrom(1000)
            recved=str(reply)
            print("Main Controller: %s " %(recved))

if __name__=='__main__':
    c=cont()
    c.send_ls()
```

Comment: Hi @keerthana. You should trim this down to a [mcve]. There's too much code here that isn't (apparently) related to the problem you're having. Stub out the `pymongo` bits, for example. Then add to your question... What exactly do you expect to happen? What exactly *is* happening? Show your actual output -- and describe the expected output. Make it clear which parts are working, and which aren't.

Comment: sure let me cut down the issue and update it and thanks

Comment: @GilHamilton Now it is updated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you only need to enable sending to a broadcast address. That's done with `client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)`.

I changed your `send_ls` as shown below and I'm able to communicate with a UDP echo program listening on port 4343. Here 192.168.40.255 is the subnet broadcast address.

```
    def send_ls(self):
        host = '192.168.40.255'
        port=4343
        address=host,port
        client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
        while (True):
            msg=input("Controller 1 :")
            client.sendto(bytearray(msg,"utf-8"),address)
            reply=client.recvfrom(1000)
            recved=str(reply)
            print("Main Controller: %s " %(recved))
```

Sample output shown below. Note that the server side didn't specify an address in the `bind`. So the server is able to receive messages sent to the broadcast address, but when it sends back, the response comes from the unicast address of the server's network adapter.

```
Controller 1 :Hello there
Main Controller: (b'Hello there', ('192.168.40.128', 4343))
Controller 1 :You still there?
Main Controller: (b'You still there?', ('192.168.40.128', 4343))
Controller 1 :
```

One more note: If your client code here *remembers* the address it gets back from the reply, then *subsequent* messages it sends don't need to go to the broadcast address. That is, simply assign `reply[1]` to `address` after the `recvfrom`, and then you won't be sending broadcasts after the first message (which is better for the performance of your network).

Comment: thanks for your post but i am trying to connect to the ip address of the server and not communicate through the subnet address.

Comment: It also works with ip address and then with broadcast address too.